# Git commit crash every time I try to do it using Hooks

Tags: git, bash

I have a directory structure like this : ~/main/sub  . In main folder, I have one git repository. It ignore the sub directory (there are more content in the main directory.) I need these two to be in two separate origins, so I added a new git repo in sub directory. But I need to commit and push both of them at the same time. So, I added the following code to the **commit-msg** hook in the main directory repo.

```
echo "Commiting Content"

now=$(date +"%c")
cd sub
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "$now Update"

echo "Commiting Content complete!"
```

But every time I run a commit, this code will execute but it will crash. An index.lock file will remain in the **sub** directory's .git folder. It won't even add the files to the commit. When I go to the sub folder and use **git status** it will tell me there are still untracked files!

Then I placed the code in a seperate bash script in the same hooks folder. Executed it in the terminal and it worked! Why does that work and the hook file fail?

Answer (score 0):

The hook runs in the root directory of your git repository. If `main` is the root directory, you have to do just `cd sub` instead of `cd main/sub`.

Do you use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)? It may be applicable in your case; it won't commit both repos at once, but if `sub` is a submodule of `main`, you can first commit `sub`, then add this commit as change to `main` and commit that. This way, someone else can check out `main` with the latest `sub` revision you committed into main.

Comment: Sorry sorry... I do cd sub only... actually its in main/dir/sub

Comment: Does the crash give any output?

Comment: No. When I commit to the main, it execute the above commands and show that the sub is also committed. But its not. And the index.lock file is there.

Comment: Interesting. Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to call git in a hook, but it should work. Anyway, you should check the return value of `git commit` and abort the commit if the command failed (use `set -e` or something). By the way, why commit-msg and not pre-commit?

Comment: Then i think its better to use a bash script to run all the commits at once right?

Comment: I think there should be a better solution for fixing your actual problem. Keeping two separate origins with different content in sync sounds fishy, because someone else might change just one of the two origins, and then your system won't work so well. One of the repository parts probably depends on the other, so I'd model it that way in the repository with a submodule.